# postgresql group and sort

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I need to reorder my query in some parameters with extracted unique field 'article' with the lowest price.
And I should sort by other parameters.

Example table:

```
article         price   id_item   name    partner weight
1000000001      500     1         Cake 1  sony    100
1000000001      1000    2         Cake 2  apple   100
1000000002      500     3         Beer 1  htc     100
1000000002      1000    4         Beer 2  htc     200
```

I need this result with sort by other parameters(name, price, partner and other...):

by name:

```
1000000002      500     3         Beer 1 htc  100
1000000001      500     1         Cake 1 sony 100
```

by name DESC:

```
1000000001      500     1         Cake 1 sony 100
1000000002      500     3         Beer 1 htc  100
```

by partner:

```
1000000002      500     3         Beer 1 htc  100
1000000001      500     1         Cake 1 sony 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to group your data and get min. [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) will take all records with minimum `price` within `article`

```
select distinct on (article)
    article, price, id_item, name
from rurbox_mod_product.item
order by article, price
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/23c7e/1)</kbd>**

if you want to sort resultset, you can use common table expression or subquery and then sort the results:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct on (article)
        article, price, id_item, name
    from item
    order by article, price
)
select *
from cte
order by name;

select *
from (
    select distinct on (article)
        article, price, id_item, name
    from item
    order by article, price  
) as A
order by name desc;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/23c7e/4)</kbd>**

Comment: If you need to find "minimum" value but then sort it using some other parameter, you will need first return the above SQL into a new table (using alias) and then do a select around it that does your other sort

Comment: Can you give me a example please?